# How to disable Yandex asking to sign in every time I try to bookmark a page?

Tags: bookmarks, yandex-browser

Every time I try to bookmark a page in Yandex, it first demands I sign in and then I have to click on a link (a second click) in order for it to save the bookmark.

[image]

I've lost a fair amount of bookmarked pages that were never bookmarked because I didn't click the second time, unlike other browsers which don't have this second prompt.

I will never create a Yandex account, so I need a way to disable this and bookmark without asking for sign-in first.

How can I disable this popup?

Comment: If Yandex is so aggressive in pushing their accounts into the market you may consider switching to a different web browser.

Comment: It's otherwise the best browser IMO